# Dropdown doesn't open after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a dropdown menu with css but it doesn't close when you click on it. So I added this function to it:

```
$(".map-button li ul li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

It closes when I click on it but it doesn't open anymore when I hover.

This is what I use to open it when I hover on it with CSS:

```
.map-button li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Menu structure:

```
<ul class="map-button">
  <li>Choose item
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li data-id="1">Item 1</li>
        <li data-id="2">Item 2</li>                 
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't hover on an element that is not being displayed. And you've just set it's display to none.

Comment: can you fiddle the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another handler:

```
 $(".map-button li").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".map-button li ul").show(); 
  });

  $(".map-button li").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".map-button li ul").hide(); 
  });
```

Comment: This is what I need! The only problem is that I have 2 dropdowns with class .map-button so when I hover it it opens both. I tried using `$(this).find('ul').hide()` and `$(this).find('ul').show()` instead but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `$(this).find('ul').hide()` and `$(this).find('ul').show()` works fine ... http://jsfiddle.net/z1eLkg77/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `hide()` sets `display: none`, but you need to set `visibility: hidden`:

```
$(this).parent().css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use all JS implementation (like @Beri suggest to you), but if you want to use CSS `:hover` to show list:

Add rule in CSS:

```
.map-button > li ul{
    display:none;
}
.map-button > li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}
```

and remove `style="display:block"` in HTML

```
<ul class="map-button">
  <li>Choose item
    <ul>
        <li data-id="1">Item 1</li>
        <li data-id="2">Item 2</li>                 
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS is ok.

[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/z1eLkg77/)

Comment: This is exactly what I have actually including my problem. When you click on an item it doesn't open anymore.